# Import local module to the Jupyter Notebook

Tags: scala, sbt, jupyter

I've a local function to transform my data on a local.

For example, when I tried to import:

> import com.company.area.project.area.functions

I've received the error:

> console: 49: error: object company is not a member of package com
>   import com.company.area.project.area.functions

I'm using Anaconda and the pip. Reading trough the web I've found this question: [Is there a pip / easy_install for Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962443/is-there-a-pip-easy-install-for-scala)

So, I noticed that there is no a equivalent to "Pip install ." we have in python.

So, the question is. How can I import a custom function in my Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to ensure that you have Scala environment enabled for your jupyter notebook.

[pixiedust](https://pixiedust.github.io/pixiedust/packagemanager.html) can help you with installing scala packages in your jupyter notebook.

A specific example in your case will be to deploy your project as a jar file to a repository or an address where you can then pass to the pixiedust package

Code example should look like this:

```py
import pixiedust
pixiedust.installPackage("https://github.com/companyrepo/jars/raw/master/dist/functions-assembly-1.0.jar")
```